# Why does $\frac{x^{\ln x}}{x}$ simplify to $x^{\ln x -1}$?

Tags: fractions, rational-functions

The question is basically in the title. Why does $\frac{x^{\ln x}}{x}$ simplify to $x^{\ln x -1}$.

Hoping for a clear explanation.

Comment: Because of $x^{a+b}=x^ax^b$, which holds for all $x>0$ and for all $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Recall for real $a,b$ we have $\frac{x^a}{x^b}=x^{a-b}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $x^a/x^b=x^{a-b}$ doesn't require $a,\,b$ to be constant.

Comment: It didn't click that the two exponents didn't have to be constants.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x}=x^{-1} \\
\frac{x^{\ln x}}{x}=x^{\ln x} \cdot \frac{1}{x}=x^{\ln x} \cdot x^{-1}$$